# Matching regex to start of input when starting at a specific posistion

Tags: javascript, regex

When using the RegExp in Javascript, if you want to match a regular expression to the start of input you can use ^ like this

```
var regEx = /^Zorg/g;  
regExp.exec( "Zorg was here" );  // This is a match
regExp.exec( "What is Zorg" );  // This is not a match
```

This does not work when starting the match in a different place in the string.

```
var regEx = /^Zorg/g;
regExp.lastIndex = 5;
regExp.exec( "What Zorg?" );  // This is not a match but i want it to
```

According to the mozilla documentation you should be able to make this a match by using the sticky flag y on the regExp.

```
var regEx = /^Zorg/gy;
regExp.lastIndex = 5;
regExp.exec( "What Zorg?" );  // This should match in firefox
```

And now to the question. Is it possible to write a regular expression that matches at start of  search when starting on different index than 0.  (Using Node right now but want to make this work in webkit as well)

```
var regEx = ????;
regExp.lastIndex = 5;
regExp.exec( "What Zorg?" );  // This this should match 
regExp.exec( "Who is Zorg?" );  // This this should not match
```

Comment: Did you mean `lastIndex` instead of `lastIndes`?

Comment: Yes i did have updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just offset it, so `/^.{5}Zorg/`  This means 'any 5 characters from the start of the line, then Zorg'.

Comment: This could work but is it possible to make the regExp expression independent of the index position some how?

Comment: Just create it from a string `var regEx = new RegExp("^.{" + lastIndex + "}Zorg");`

Comment: Yes thanks that works but i am just worried that if I do this on large strings /^.{2456}Zorg/ it will loop throug 2456 chars if starting at index 0. Insted of starting at index 2456. Will do a test.

Comment: You could just cut the string prior to testing the regex if you prefer, but if the Javascript regex implementation is even vaguely optimised then it shouldn't make a lot of difference speed-wise.

Comment: There is no real difference between /^[\s\S]{275}Zorg/g and /^[\s\S]{268331}Zorg/g the later is even a little bitt faster though it is about 4-5 times slower than cutting the string and running /^Zorg/g and about 5-6 times slower then running /Zorg/g and setting lastIndex on the regexp